# How to reverse the output order

Tags: javascript, html

I want to output the results in the order they were entered. For example, if the input is in the order abcd, I want the output to be abcd as well. However, the problem with my code is that it keeps changing the order and outputting it as dcba. How can I reverse the output order?

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>지화 번역기</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>지화 번역</h1>
  <video id="webcam" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
  <div id="result"></div>

  <script>
    async function setupCamera() {
      const video = document.getElementById('webcam');
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
      video.srcObject = stream;

      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
          resolve(video);
        };
      });
    }

    async function loadTeachableMachineModel() {
      const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/models/o49biL0_D/model.json');
      return model;
    }

    async function predictWithTeachableMachineModel(model, video) {
      setInterval(async () => {
        const webcamImage = tf.browser.fromPixels(video);
        const resizedImage = tf.image.resizeBilinear(webcamImage, [224, 224]);
        const normalizedImage = resizedImage.div(255.0);
        const batchedImage = normalizedImage.expandDims(0);

        const predictions = await model.predict(batchedImage);
        const classId = predictions.argMax(1).dataSync()[0];
        const className = await getClassLabel(classId);

        displayResult(className);

        webcamImage.dispose();
        resizedImage.dispose();
        normalizedImage.dispose();
        batchedImage.dispose();
        predictions.dispose();
      }, 5000);
    }

    async function getClassLabel(classId) {
      const labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']; // 클래스 레이블 목록
      return labels[classId];
    }

    function displayResult(result) {
      const resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');

      // 5초에 한 번 결과 추가
      resultDiv.innerHTML = `${result}${resultDiv.innerHTML}`;
    }

    async function init() {
      const video = await setupCamera();
      const model = await loadTeachableMachineModel();
      predictWithTeachableMachineModel(model, video);
    }

    init();
  </script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve whats the end goal ?

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like you are prepending the new result to the beginning of the "resultDiv.innerHTML" each time. but you want to print the results the way you enter the input so what it will do is show the results in reversing order.

Try doing this:

```
resultDiv.innerHTML += result;
```

Instead of:

```
resultDiv.innerHTML = `${result}${resultDiv.innerHTML}`;
```

Comment: Please read the [AI-Ban policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) which forbids the posting of AI-generated content. SO is a repository for developers who need the help of other professionals, not someone who just gives them the AI output they could have used in the first place. The technical understanding of the AI does not meet that professionalism as your answer perfectly shows (it uses an outdated method open to security risks: XSS).